# jQuery Ui Draggable not working with overflow table

Tags: jquery, html, draggable

I am having an undesired effect when I drag a div from a container div which is set as overflow: scroll.
css code

```
table {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      height: 160px;
      verflow-y:scroll;
}
thead, tbody, tr, td{ 
      display: block;} 
tbody td, thead th {
      idth: 25%;
      float: left;}
```

jquery code

```
$('.item').draggable({

    revert: function(event, ui){
        var num = Number($(this).attr('id').split('item').join(''));
        $(this).data('ui-draggable').originalitemtion = {
            top: defaultitemArr[num].top,
            left: defaultitemArr[num].left
         }
         return !event;
    }
});
$('#map').droppable(  {

    drop: function (ev, ui) {

    }
});
```